# spring 3.0 and JSRI68 support

Tags: spring, portlet

can anyone tell me if JSR168 is supported by Spring 3.0? I'm running into difficulties but cant find anywhere in the Spring documentation that says you have to move to Portlet2 spec

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring portlet 3.0's DispatcherPortlet class has a dependency on a class (javax.portlet.MimeResponse) which is new in JSR 268.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://opensource.atlassian.com/confluence/spring/display/JSR168/Home;jsessionid=0101D59B765F21FF6CE8E133695C8FB6):

> The Spring Portlet MVC framework provides a complete MVC layer for the JSR-168 Portlet API in the same way that Spring Web MVC does for the Servlet API. Wherever possible the APIs and capabilities are the same between the two frameworks. However, unlike most other portlet MVC frameworks, the unique workflow of the JSR-168 API is completely preserved, including the separation of the ActionRequest and the RenderRequest.

Comment: thanks, but does this count for Spring 3.0? there appears to be a dependency within spring portelt on JSR 268 however my application is not ready for that upgrade

Comment: haha looks like i'll be sticking with 2.5, thanks for you input