# Spring MVC 2.5 servlet/portlet compatible URL

Tags: java, spring-mvc, portlet, jsr168

I'm a writing an application using Spring MVC which has to run as a *servlet* and a *portlet*. This is fair easy to do in Spring 3 (JSR-286) but I must use portlet 1.0 specification (JSR-168). In order to be compatible with it I downgraded Spring MVC to 2.5 ([more information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063989/spring-3-0-and-jsri68-support)).

Everything works fine expect I'm not able to generate servlet/portlet compatible URL!

Using Spring 3, I would write:

```
<spring:url value="/foo">
  <spring:param name="action" value="foo"/>
</spring>
```

In Spring 2.5 there is no `spring:url` tag. I tried with `c:url` but it only generates servlet compatible URL (not portlet).

How can I achieve servlet/portlet compatible URL generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the solution below, but maybe it will help.

You could use the portlet tag for portlet compatible urls :

```
<%@ taglib uri=”http://java.sun.com/portlet” prefix=”portlet” %>
...
<portlet:actionURL ... >
    <portlet:param name="action" value="foo">
</portlet:actionURL>
```

(I recommend that you to take a look at the [Java Portlet 1.0 specification (JSR-168)](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr168/index.html) "Portlet Tag Library" chapter for detailed information about this tag)

Then, to generate either a portlet or a servlet url, you could use a condition that detects if you are currently using Portlet or Servlet (I don't know if it is possible) :

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="usingPortlet">
        <portlet:actionURL ... > ... </portlet:actionURL>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:url ... > ... </c:url>
    </c:otherwise> 
<c:choose>
```